# Get test suite id using Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying the below API, to get the suite ID using test case ID,

```
http://tfsb.xxx.com/xxx/xxxSoftware/_api/_testManagement/suites?testCaseId=185295&api-version=5.0
```

But I always get the below response:

> 404 - File or directory not found.

Can any you please tell me how to get the suite ID using testcase ID for Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct API, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) there is a special API for this - [Get Suites By Test Case Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20suites%20by%20test%20case%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/test/suites?testCaseId={testCaseId}&api-version=5.0
```

Comment: Can you please guide how to add authorization in this API?

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this all morning. Finally figured out how to get it to work. You should *not* put the project / team name in the URL. For example, most API calls look like:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/
```

However, the correct URL for *this* api call should look like:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/
```

In other words just put the base organization but do *not* put the project/team.

Same if you are using a dedicated organization url, instead of:

```
https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/Bigproject/_apis/
```

you must do

```
https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/_apis/
```